# Does anyone know how to make a custom face distortion pack for Spark AR?

Tags: augmented-reality, 3dsmax, spark-ar-studio

I have been toying around with the Spark AR platform for making augmented reality filters and it's been going quite well. The only thing I would like to know, however, is if it is possible to create your own Face Distortion pack. I have been using the one offered by Spark AR but it just doesn't reach what I would like to achieve. I've managed to adjust the Face Distortion 3D object in 3DS max, but using that in Spark AR doesn't yield the correct results. Instead, any deformation I might adjust in the deformation settings will result in the face mesh just becoming larger.

Basically, does anyone have a better insight in how to use custom Face Distortion packs for Spark AR. Will provide more information if necessary of course. Any information welcome. Thanks!